# jQuery UI tooltip won't close when using dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code to simulate an ajax call to fetch the tooltip content:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: 'a',
    content: function(result) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            result('foo');
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

If you move the mouse on and away from the link several times, it will sooner or later get to a point where the tooltip doesn't close, even though the mouse isn't hovering the link.

Any ideas what might be causing it or how to solve it?

[jQuery UI toolip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position)

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/Z2R43/

Comment: Google is your friend. ("jquery tooltip ajax bug") JQuery UI tooltip bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8740 The comments show some discussion and at least one workaround for someones situation.

Comment: Interestingly the fiddle linked here is the same one in the ticket.

Comment: @LeeMeador I've seen it. But since it isn't solved there, I'm wondering if someone here knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before where moving the mouseover the link causes the event to fire each time and stacks them up in the background. I solved the issue with the [hoverIntent plugin](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent) which would only fire the event if the user waited on the link for a specified amount of time.

You can do the same in Tooltip by adding in a delay on the show event which does the same thing:

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: 'a',
    content: function(result) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            result('foo');
        }, 500);
    },
    show: {
        delay: 250
      }
});
```

Comment: Ok, and what's the connection between the timeout delay (500ms) and the show delay (250ms). What made you pick those numbers? The problem with this code is that you assume that 250ms is enought. That might not be the case.

Comment: Nothing in particular, set Show delay to whatever you want. It just means the user must stop on the link for at least 250ms before the tooltip show event will fire. Default is immediate (0ms) I believe

Comment: I see your point. This has generally helped minimize the issue for me, since it is usually unlikely the user will move in/out a link like crazy. Usual issue is when a user moves their move and "accidentally" hovers.

Comment: Yea, it will mnimize, but not get rid of it. Thanks for the suggestion though. I'll give you an upvote and see if someone else answers.